# Presentation topic for computational solutions to problems involving probability

Tags: probability-theory, research

I'm looking for interesting applications of computing science for finding the probability of otherwise difficult problems. This is for an undergraduate level presentation in a probability course of around 30 minutes, from a comp sci major who has beginner to intermediate skills in both probability/statistics and comp sci.

I hope to have a topic that is interesting and can be explained without entirely relying on proofs and equations.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]! Unfortunately, your question is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format. We prefer questions that have objectively correct answers that will be useful both to the asker and others who have the same question in the future. What is or is not a suitable topic for study, projects or research is very much a matter of opinion and depends crucially on the interests and skills of the person who will be doing the work and the support that will be available to them. This is a question that you should be asking your professors.

Comment: Are you looking for examples where computers are useful for computing some probability? If so, a classic example is the evaluation of $\pi$. Sample points from the uniform distribution over the unit square, and count how many fell inside the circle bounded in it. This probability equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$. You might be interested in the [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) in general.

Comment: That said, the main methods by which I think computation can help in determining 'probability' of some event are 1) numerical methods for tricky distributions. The normal distribution, for example, is often computed numerically. 2) Making automatic inferences by using machine learning or artificial intelligence. and 3) simulations